# Order of solutions NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

I'm having a problem with Mathematica's NSolve function. I wrote the next example to illustrate the type of behavior that NSolve exhibits.

```
tab=Table[{x,y}/.NSolve[{x^2+y^2==1,Sin[t]x+Cos[t]y==0},{x,y}][[1]],{t,0,\[Pi],\[Pi]/10}];

Show[Table[Graphics[{Text[i,tab[[i]]]},PlotRange-> {{-1.5,1.5},{-1.5,1.5}}],{i,1,10,1}]]
```

[image]

In this example I'm solving the system of equations and there are two solutions. I'm getting the first solution given by NSolve. I expected there to be some continuity between the solutions, but apparently the NSolve jump back and forth across the solutions. Is there any way to prevent this kind of behavior so that the solutions are continuous?

Comment: As an additional suggestion, whenever you find yourself iterating over all elements of a list in sequence, consider mapping a function over the list: `Graphics[MapIndexed[Text[First[#2], #1]&, tab], PlotRange -> 1.5]` is equivalent to your second line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is an evaluation issue in your table. Just do the following. Add `Evaluate` on the result of your `NSolve` along with the `[[1]]` at the end, so this order gets sorted out before the Table gets hold on the result.

```
tab = Table[Evaluate[{x, y} /. 
   NSolve[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, Sin[t] x + Cos[t] y == 0}, {x, y}][[1]]], 
      {t, 0, π, π/10}];

Show[Table[
  Graphics[{Text[i, tab[[i]]]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}], {i, 1, 10, 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I myself prefer to do things step by step instead of lumping all code in one line like so many seem to enjoy doing.

It is more clear and easier to maintain:

```
tab = {x, y} /. NSolve[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, Sin[t] x + Cos[t] y == 0}, {x, y}];
tab = Table[First@tab, {t, 0, π, π/10}];
Show[Table[Graphics[{Text[i, tab[[i]]]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}], {i, 1, 10, 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not only the code is more clear now, you do not have to do `Evaluate` inside the Table command.

btw, `Solve` also works here instead of `NSolve`